# How to (efficiently) find intersection of two polyhedral cones?

Tags: convex-polytopes, cones

I have two polyhedral cones represented by their rays. I am looking to find their intersection, which would also be a polyhedral cone, hopefully efficiently. Does anybody know a way to do that?

Thanks

Deepanshu

Comment: More details would help. Are you trying to find the intersection numerically or give a simple description in some sense? What kind of an answer would be acceptable? What space are you working in?

Comment: At an REU in 2010, I was a part of a team that designed and implemented an algorithm along these lines as a part of a project to visualize piecewise flat manifolds. The relevant section of our paper begins at the bottom of page 8 at this link: http://math.arizona.edu/~asp/2010/CrouchDossJohnsonKiviatLanierpaper.pdf Hope something there is useful!

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you are working in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d > 3$.
There are specialized algorithms in $d=2,3$.

Here is one route.
You have, essentially, what is known as the *V-representation* of your polytopal cones, V=vertex.
An alternate representation is the *H-representation*, H=halfspace, the intersection of halfspaces. If you convert each cone's V-representation to an H-representation, then you have reduced your problem to intersecting all the halfspaces defining both cones.

One can convert between V- and H-representations via a variety of software packages.
E.g., it can be accomplished in *R*; see [this link](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/rcdd/library/rcdd/html/scdd.html).
Perhaps a better place to start is *polymake*; see [this web page](http://polymake.org/doku.php/tutorial/apps_polytope).

The intersection of halfspaces can be accomplished by a wider variety of software, including polymake and [*qhull*](http://www.qhull.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Another code you may wish to try is 4ti2's rays-function. It can also be called via polymake.